# Why are only some tables shown in QGIS when I connect to database?

Tags: qgis, database, connection

For a project I started to work with pgAdmin and QGIS, so I'm quite new in these things and I have a problem with the connection of the database to the QGIS.

I can connect myself to the database and can see the SCHEMAS "geo" and "public" and also some of the tables .. but only some of them, the one I want to connect myself to, doesn't pop up and I don't know why.. 
I created it like this:

```
-- Table: geo.casa

-- DROP TABLE geo.casa;

CREATE TABLE geo.casa
(
  id_casa serial NOT NULL,
  id_comunidad integer,
  geom geo.geometry(Point,4326),
  CONSTRAINT casa_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_casa),
  CONSTRAINT casa_comunidad_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_comunidad)
      REFERENCES geo.comunidad (id_comunidad) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE geo.casaa
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I'm not sure what kind of information you need, so just tell me if you need anything else!

Comment: What you're really looking for is a tutorial on database security models, using PostgreSQL as the primary example.  Setting ownership to the postgres user is more likely to be in the Don't list than the Do.